# No shadows on my mesh becuase of a mistake in my shader Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, cg

I am writing a toon water shader, and I want it to be lit by a directional light. I got it working but I think there is somthing wrong with the normals because there are no shadows between the wave. I hope that someone can find the mistake I made and thank you in advance.

[image]

```
Shader "Custom/NoobShader_03" {
        Properties {
            _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)

            _Scale ("Wave Scale", float) = 0.6
            _Frequency ("Frequency", float) = 1
            _Speed ("Speed", float) = 0.5

            _Scale2 ("Wave Scale", float) = 0.6
            _Frequency2 ("Frequency", float) = 1
            _Speed2 ("Speed", float) = 1
        }
        SubShader {
            Pass{
            Tags { "LightMode" = "ForwardBase"}
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            float4 _Color;

            float _Scale;
            float _Frequency;
            float _Speed;

            float _Scale2;
            float _Frequency2;
            float _Speed2;

            float4 _LightColor0;

            struct VertexOutput
            {
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                float3 nor : NORMAL;
                float4 col : COLOR;
            };

            struct VertexInput
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float3 normal : NORMAL;
            };

            struct FragmentOutput
            {
                float4 color : COLOR;
            };

            VertexOutput vert (VertexInput i)
            {
                VertexOutput VOUT;
                float randomNum = 1 / _Time;
                float newPos = _Scale * sin(_Time.w * _Speed + i.vertex.x * _Frequency);
                float newPos2 = _Scale2 * cos(_Time.w * _Speed2 + i.vertex.z * _Frequency2);
                //i.vertex.y += newPos;
                float4 tempPos = i.vertex;
                tempPos.y += newPos * newPos2;

                VOUT.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP,tempPos);
                VOUT.nor = float3(mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP,tempPos).xyz);

                float3 normalDirection = normalize( mul( float4( VOUT.nor, 0.0 ), _World2Object).xyz);
                float3 lightDirection;
                float atten = 1.0;

                lightDirection = normalize(_WorldSpaceLightPos0.xyz);

                float3 diffuseRefflection = atten * _LightColor0.xyz * _Color.rgb * max( 0.0, dot(normalDirection, lightDirection));

                VOUT.col = float4(diffuseRefflection, 0.0);

                return VOUT;
            }

            FragmentOutput frag(VertexOutput v) 
            {
                FragmentOutput FOUT;
                FOUT.color = v.col + _Color;
                return FOUT;
            }
            ENDCG
            }
        } 
        FallBack "Diffuse"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quick answer about your normals

```
float3 normalDirection = normalize( mul( float4( VOUT.nor, 0.0 ), _World2Object).xyz);
```

Normals are given in local aka object space.  You need to convert to world space.  The order of your multiplication is wrong. It should be:

```
float3 normalDirection = normalize( mul( _World2Object, float4( VOUT.nor, 0.0 )).xyz);
```

which is equivalent to:

```
float3 normalDirection = normalize( mul( float4( VOUT.nor, 0.0 ), _Object2World).xyz);
```

You generally put the transform matrix before the vector you're transforming.